# How to add markers with series with jvectormap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I am trying to add markers to a map. The markers have values, so each one have different values. I expect that the circles will have different radius depending on these values. This is what I do:

```
geochart.removeAllMarkers();
for (var i=0; i<selected_locations.length; i++) {
  loc = selected_locations[i];
  geochart.addMarker(i, locations_data[loc], addedSeries[i] || {}) ;
}
```

`addedSeries` is an Array, like `[12,0,0,610]`

`selected_locations` is an Array, like `["11", "12", "5", "2"]`

`locations_data` is an Array, like

```
{
 ...
 "11": {"latLng": [37.89,-4.78], "name": "Location A"},
 "12": {"latLng": [37.18,-3.59], "name": "Location B"},
 ...
}
```

`geochart` is a `jvm.Map` instance.

The current behavior I get is that the markers are being created, but the radius are always the same.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easy if you browse the code, but a little tricky. It seems I need to add a list of values, one for each marker type declared on `series` section of the `map`. This is my `map`:

```
var geochart = new jvm.Map({
  container: $('.spain-map'),
  map: 'es_mill_en',
  markers: markers,
  series: {
    markers: [{
      attribute: 'r',
      scale: [5, 20],
      values: [...]
    },{
      attribute: 'fill',
      scale: ['#00CC00', '#CC0000'],
      values: [...]
    }]
  }
});
```

So this is how I resolve it:

```
geochart.addMarker(i, 
                   locations_data[loc], 
                   [ addedSeries[i], addedSeries[i] ] || {}
                   );
```

Comment: This does not work (for me) without specifying the min and max (not just scale and values) inside the 'r' marker attribute object. jVectormap version: 2.0.3.